# AFP Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algorithm

Tags: isabelle

For the [AFP](http://afp.sourceforge.net/) entry [Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algorithm](http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/Dijkstra_Shortest_Path.shtml), both the proof outline and proof document were nonexistent *. Unfortunately, I did not find an `IsaMakefile` either to build those documents locally. What is the best way to get those documents?

Another question, as the `Dijkstra.thy` depends on a lot of other theories, is there a way to load everything faster?

*) *It is fixed now.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(There seems to be something broken at AFP right now, please tell the editors about it.)

In general, you can download the sources of AFP entries and produce the documents yourself like this:

- Get and unpack [all AFP sources](http://afp.sourceforge.net/release/afp-current.tar.gz) -- downloading separate entries is offered as well, but then you have to disentangle dependencies manually.
- Invoke `isabelle build` like this:

  ```
  isabelle build -d afp-2013-03-02 -o document=pdf -v Dijkstra_Shortest_Path
  ```

  Here `afp-2013-03-02` is the directory that was obtained by unpacking the current AFP sources.

See also the [Isabelle System manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2013/doc/system.pdf) about "Isabelle sessions and build management", which is all new in Isabelle2013.

See `isabelle build -b` there to make things load faster, by producing persistent heap images from sessions.

Comment: Odd, I've just tried again to see that it really works.  The error about `Bad session root directory: "afp-2013-03-02"` means that Isabelle build did not find the `afp-2013-03-02/ROOTS` file, so it was either absent, unreadable, whatever.  The `-d` option specifies a directory relative to the current one, but you've had that as far as I can tell.

Comment: I take everything back! My isabelle start script hab a `cd ~/Isabelle2013/bin/` in it

Answer (score 4):

The links in the AFP entry were indeed broken and should now be fixed again, sorry about that.

As Makarius writes, the AFP new uses Isabelle's new build system, i.e. has a `ROOT` file for each entry that can be used to check the associated theories and build the document.

Makarius' answer is pretty much the official way to do it, although I would additionally recommend setting up the AFP as a component. This gives you the following steps:

- [Download the AFP](http://afp.sourceforge.net/download.shtml) to e.g. `~/afp`
- Set it up as component e.g. by adding `~/afp` to `~/.isabelle/Isabelle2013/components` (see also [AFP as a component](http://afp.sourceforge.net/using.shtml))
- build the entry with

  `isabelle afp_build Dijkstra_Shortest_Path`

Answer (score 1):

You can also have jEdit build the heap image for you. If the AFP is setup as a component (see the other answers for that), just start jEdit with

```
isabelle jedit -d '$AFP' -l Dijkstra_Shortest_Path
```

and jEdit will select Dijkstra_Shortest_Path as base logic and (re)build it if necessary.

If you make regular use of the AFP, it might be useful to add the AFP path by default. For this, create a file ROOTS in `$ISABELLE_HOME_USER` with the line `$AFP` in it (or add this line, if the file already exists).